# Docker container has no dns configured with custom network

Tags: docker, dns, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running `Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6` on `ubuntu 14.04`.

If I do

```
docker run -it busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
```

It's working.

Now if I try

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run -it --network mynetwork busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
```

It's not working anymore.

I first thought of an internet access problem but with

```
docker run -it --network mynetwork busybox ping -c 1 216.58.201.228
```

it's working again.

So the problem seems to be a dns problem.

I remarked

```
docker run -it busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net
```

and

```
docker run -it --network mynetwork busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ovh.net
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

And eventually

```
docker run -it --network mynetwork --dns 213.186.33.99 busybox ping -c 1 www.google.com
```

is also working.

Is it normal ?  Reading the docker documentation I thought I had read that the resolv.conf of the host was 'mounted' in the container.  Why not with the custom network ?

What's the solution ?